# Thin client boot from server

Tags: 16.04, boot, client, ltsp

I have just installed a ubuntu 16.04 lts(Xenial Xerus) server, to test with a thin-client to boot from it.

I have so far been successful,and after a week though the isc-dhcp-service is running well and with the right NIC, this is the output i get from the thin-client side.

```
CLIENT MAC ADDRR: 00 14 C2 05 A2 F6 GUIDE..
CLIENT IP: 192.168.67.20 MASK: 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY IP: 192.168.67.1
TFTP.
PXE-T01: File Not Found
PXE-E3B: TFTP Error - File Not Found

PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
```

I'm a bit confused, I did try ltsp-build-client, but i'm still getting this same message.

Where have I gone wrong, or better yet, what should I do?

Help from anyone.

Thanks.